# Convert year, month and date into milliseconds

Tags: calculus

Say of I have a date of birth (dob) like 1991-7-12, how can I convert it to milliseconds in total?

I have the current milliseconds from 1970-1-1 as 1505674059277. From this I can calculate how many days and months like this:

```
1505674059277/(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)
```

Months:

```
1505674059277/(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30)
```

When some one says their birth day like mentioned above (1991-7-12), I want to calculate how many years, month and days they are old.

I am finding it difficult to convert someone's (dob) into milliseconds. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: @Peter I don't have the number of seconds, I have date of birth. I want to convert it to milliseconds using something like `1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 * 365`. What should I multiply? year? month? or day? I am confused.

Comment: Now, I understand. Just determine how old a person is in days and multiply the result with $86 \ 400 \ 000$. I do not think that there is a shortcut leading to an accurate result.

Comment: Well, a day has $24$ hours, hence $1\ 440$ minutes , hence $86\ 400$ seconds, hence $86\ 400\ 000$ milliseconds. Exactly the factor you just mentioned

Comment: I think there is a formula , but neither do I know it, nor will it be an easy formula. It will contain modulo-expressions. Maybe, Wolfram Alpha can count the days ? I will try it... Yes, here is an example : https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=number+of+days+1.1.2000+to+21.7.2017

Comment: @Pater thank you, so far I am just calculating by taking (2017 - birthyear) * 365 to get days. But i know there is leap year consideration. That's why I was wondering about it. If you feel like there is something out there, you can post it an answer, i will gladly accept it!

Comment: There is also the [leap second](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second). According to Wikipedia "Since this system of correction was implemented in 1972, 27 leap seconds have been inserted, the most recent on December 31, 2016 at 23:59:60 UTC."